# When sharpening 3/8" chainsaw chains, do you use the same file for 3/8" low-profile as you'd use for regular?

Tags: sharpening

I'm in a bad spot because I got a "5/32 file & file-guide" kit but it doesn't seem to 'fit well' with any of my chains (all 5/32", some low-profile some regular)

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you have not done so already, please take the time to visit the [tour]. Maybe show or describe what you mean by "does not fit well". Also, it's probably best to put the actual quesiton you are asking in the body of the question with an [edit]. That way, everything is in the same place for ease of answering.

Comment: @user7577 You should keep in mind that the angle of the cutter is different on different manufacturers chains. Some 30 degrees, some 35 degrees. also the height of the cutter differs too.

Comment: If you could [edit] your post to include (reasonably small) pictures of the chain and the kit that would be helpful.  Alternatively add links to the products.